# Unable to read decimal numbers from XML

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, cultureinfo, visual-c#-express-2010

I have a problem, when I try to read XML file, which has decimal values, like 24.5478785 - it gives back error:

> There is error in XML document

Can someone please advise, why is this happening? Decimal part in file looks like: `<interval>22,555555</interval>`

My code:

```
private void OpenFileXml(bool runIt, string file)
{
    //Get data from XML file
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ActionsEntry));
    using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
    {
        try
        {
            ActionsEntry entry = (ActionsEntry)ser.Deserialize(fs);
            lvActions.Items.Clear();
            foreach (ActionsEntryAction ae in entry.Action)
            {
                string point = ae.X.ToString() + "," + ae.Y.ToString();
                string interval = (ae.interval).ToString("F6");
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(new string[] { point, ((ClickType)(ae.Type)).ToString(), interval, ae.Text });
                ActionEntry acion = new ActionEntry(ae.X, ae.Y, ae.Text, ae.interval, (ClickType)(ae.Type));
                lvi.Tag = acion;
                lvActions.Items.Add(lvi);
            }

            if (runIt)
            {
                btnStart.PerformClick();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Clicer", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

XML file:
[image]

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ActionsEntry xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Action>
<X>824</X>
<Y>456</Y>
<Text />
<interval>22,555555</interval>
<Type>0</Type>
</Action>
</ActionsEntry>
```

Comment: Have you tried to change the CultureInfo ?

Comment: Don't really have a clue, what is that...

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437946/xml-deserialization-crashes-on-decimal-parse-due-to-formatting I think it has the answer your looking for.

Comment: please post your xml instead of a picture

Comment: @RenukaDeshmukh Added

Comment: @hbrock Where is he trying to parse the decimal, AFAICS he's just bringing it in as a string (with a `.ToString("F6")`??).

Comment: There are likely more errors than caused by using comma as decimal separator (covered by good explanation I used as duplicate), but that should get you started. Side note: using non-standard formatting for numbers (i.e. locale specific) in XML is bad idea - consider using format with dot as decimal separator as recommended for XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML serializer uses a standard format to serialize/deserialize float/date time and it doesn't actually care about CultureInfo. this problem is due to the float conversion in thread's `cultureInfo`.

this might not be the best option but you can try to change culture info before serialization.

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
```

or either you can implement a custom Serializer. here is a nice article

[Injecting XML Serialization for formatting decimal properties](https://dotnet-experience.blogspot.com/2011/05/injecting-xml-serialization-for.html)

another option is to change `ActionsEntry` class and implement a wrapper property to convert `interval` and ignore `thread's cultureInfo` to solve this problem.

```
public class ActionsEntry
{
    public Action Action { get; set; }
}

public class Action
{
    public int X { get; set; }

    public int Y { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public float interval { get; set; }

    private string _intervalString;
    [XmlElement("interval")]
    public string IntervalString
    {
        get
        {
            return _intervalString;
        }
        set
        {
            _intervalString = value;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                interval = float.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }
    }

    public int Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No luck, same error.

Comment: in which line it raises the exception? where did you add this code?

Comment: have you tried to change xml element to  `<interval>22.555555</interval>` replace `,` with `.`  does it work this way or not?

Comment: same error with both :(

Comment: what is the`inner exception` ?

Answer (score 0):

> You have not provided the structure of your Action and ActionsEntry
>   classes, so I went ahead with following assumptions

```
public class ActionsEntry
    {
        public ActionsEntry() { Actions = new List<Action>(); }
        [XmlElement("Action")]
        public List<Action> Actions { get; set; }

    }

    public class Action
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("interval")]
        public string Interval { get; set; }
        public int Type { get; set; }

    }
```

Then, in the for loop I tried:

```
ActionsEntry entry = (ActionsEntry)ser.Deserialize(fs);
foreach (var action in entry.Actions)
{
    string interval = action.Interval.Replace(',', '.');
    decimal intvrl = Decimal.Parse(interval);
    Console.WriteLine(intvrl);
}
```